# Many-to-many wordforms in Sphinx

Tags: search, sphinx

In Sphinx, it seems like there should logically be a way to use wordforms like actual synonyms (which offer a many-to-many possibility). For example, I want any instance of the words `photo`, `image`, and `picture` in the search string to match any instance of those words in the searched content. Is such a thing possible without returning a `WARNING: duplicate wordform found - skipped` message during the index process?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
image > photo
picture > photo
```

Words `image` and `picture` will map to `photo`, and the word `photo` will be processed 'as-is'.

An example:

```
mysql> call keywords('photo image picture', 'idx');
+------+-----------+------------+
| qpos | tokenized | normalized |
+------+-----------+------------+
| 1    | photo     | photo      |
| 2    | image     | photo      |
| 3    | picture   | photo      |
+------+-----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

You can see that the normal form for all those words is `photo`.

Comment: Does that not work out to be a one-way mapping though? I see your example as mapping `image` and `picture` in the searched content to `photo` (so that searching for `photo` will find those two words), but not resulting in a search for `image` finding results that contain the word `picture`.

Comment: It is one way, but its the normalized version stored in index, and as the query is also normalized - they will all match each other.